# Find the left-most border of a minimum-plateau of a function

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a costly calculation where I want to find the first / left-most occurrence of 0.

[image: plot]

How can I do this most effectively / easily?

[`scipy.optimize.fmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) does not converge, neither do the [`scipy.optimize.minimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) algorithms I have tried so far (since there is no gradient on the right side).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Binary search over the support interval? If f(mid) is close to 0, set [low, mid] for the next iteration; else if f(mid) > 0, set [mid, high]. Stop once you've hit a reasonable precision for mid. That'd require a logarithmic number of evaluations of f.

Comment: @Nelewout I'm sorry, the example plot was insufficient. I updated the plot above.

Comment: I am probably missing something but what is the input? A set of points, a function...? And in the second graph, what is the point you're looking for? Is 1e-9 "zero" enough? Finally you're looking for this starting at x=0.10, in the bounded interval above? Sorry for the questions.

Comment: @evilmandarine It's a numerical function - a function consisting of several numerical solvers. Thus it's not reaching an analytical 0. So anything "small enough" is fine - say 1e-7. I know that this function is strictly monotonic decreasing on (0, α], where α is the point it reaches "zero". I don't want to write my own solver since what appears easy at first glance, has a thousand ways to fail.

Comment: Any chance you can provide more information about the function?

Comment: @evilmandarine Sure, what do you need? It's a chain of several scipy solvers on a model. I don't know what else I can tell you about it.